# How can I add item on localStroge through ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, onclick, local-storage

I don't understand how I can add an item on localStroge with the handle change method in react js.

The problem is I want to add a favorite list. When I click the favorite list all checkbox fill I need to control them.

I want to store the filled item in my local storage. **handlechange** function fill all favorite icon why?

Every click will be a single item fill. Is it possible to Material UI or Martial UI checkBox icon? How can I handle it?

[image]

Here is my UI view

[image]

```
function Main() {

  //   Here is my state define
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(
    localStorage.getItem("love") === "true"
  );

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem("love", `${e.target.checked}`);
    setChecked(e.target.checked);
    console.log(e.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row mt-5">
        {isLoading ? (
          <>
            {Array.from({ length }).map((_, i) => (
              <MainLoading key={i} />
            ))}
          </>
        ) : error ? (
          <p>Error occured</p>
        ) : (
          <>
            {data?.map((product) => (
              <div className="col-md-3 mb-5 text-center" key={product.id}>
                <img
                  className="w-100"
                  style={{ height: "200px", objectFit: "contain" }}
                  src={product.image}
                  alt=""
                />
                <div>{product.title.substring(0, 20)}</div>
                <button
                  onClick={() => handelAddTocard(product)}
                  className="mt-3"
                >
                  Add to card
                </button>
                <button>
                  <Link
                    to={`/details/${product.id}`}
                    className="mt-3 text-decoration-none text-black"
                  >
                    view details
                  </Link>
                </button>

                {/* How can i control evey single item  */}
                <Checkbox
                  checked={checked}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
                  checkedIcon={<Favorite />}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a boolean and you have no way to identify a specific item.

If you want to favorite multiple items, I would use something like this:

```js
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loveIds") || "[]")
  );

  const handleCheck = (id, productChecked) => {
    const newItems = productChecked ? [...checked, id] : checked.filter(x => x !== id);
    localStorage.setItem("loveIds", JSON.stringify(newItemS));
    setChecked(newItems);
    console.log(newItems);
  };

   // ...
    <Checkbox
                  checked={checked}
                  onChange={(e) => handleCheck(product.id, e.target.checked)}
                  icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
                  checkedIcon={<Favorite />}
                />
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: checked is not iterable....... throw an error when I click my  Checkbox

Comment: Clear you localStorage :) I updated the code too

Comment: Same problem not working

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem to use includes() array method. Material-ui checkbox take Boolean value.

I use redux hook to useSeclactor. Thank you.